# Why does stdout not flush when connecting to a process that is run with supervisord?

Tags: python, unix, terminal, supervisord

I am using Supervisor (process controller written in python) to start and control my web server and associated services.  I find the need at times to enter into pdb (or really ipdb) to debug when the server is running.  I am having trouble doing this through Supervisor.

Supervisor allows the processes to be started and controlled with a daemon called supervisord, and offers access through a client called supervisorctl.  This client allows you to attach to one of the foreground processes that has been started using a 'fg' command.  Like this:

```
supervisor> fg webserver
```

All logging data gets sent to the terminal.  But I do not get any text from the pdb debugger.  It does accept my input so stdin seems to be working.

As part of my investigation I was able to confirm that neither `print` nor `raw_input` send and text out either; but in the case of `raw_input` the stdin is indeed working.

I was also able to confirm that this works:

```
sys.stdout.write('message')
sys.flush()
```

I though that when I issued the `fg` command that it would be as if I had run the process in the foreground in the standard terminal ... but it appears that supervisorctl is doing something more.  Regular printing does not flush for example. Any ideas?

**How can I get pdb, standard prints, etc to work properly when connecting to the foreground terminal using the `fg` command in supervisorctl?**

(Possible helpful ref: http://supervisord.org/subprocess.html#nondaemonizing-of-subprocesses)

Comment: This this: `fflush('stdout');` That should do the trick.

Answer (score 8):

It turns out that python defaults to buffering its output stream.  In certain cases (such as this one) - it results in output being detained.

Idioms like this exist:

```
sys.stdout = os.fdopen(sys.stdout.fileno(), 'w', 0)
```

to force the buffer to zero.

But the better alternative I think is to start the base python process in an unbuffered state using the `-u` flag.  Within the supervisord.conf file it simply becomes:

```
command=python -u script.py
```

ref: http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONUNBUFFERED

Also note that this dirties up your log file - especially if you are using something like ipdb with ANSI coloring.  But since it is a dev environment it is not likely that this matters.

If this is an issue - another solution is to stop the process to be debugged in supervisorctl  and then run the process temporarily in another terminal for debugging.  This would keep the logfiles clean if that is needed.

Comment: Darn, you got your own answer before I could get round to posting one for you. :-) Note: when python detects that `stdout` is a terminal ([`os.isatty()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.isatty) is `True`) then `stdout` is opened using line buffering (so `buffering=1` instead of `0`).

Comment: Ha!  Sad to say that's what happens when you're working over the weekend and you're inherently impatient. Thanks for "almost" answering ... and the additional info on the `os.isatty()`.

Comment: I'm hoping this will sort out my script not writing to file when using supervisor?

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your webserver redirects its own stdout (internally) to a log file (i.e. it ignores supervisord's stdout redirection), and that prevents supervisord from controlling where its stdout goes.

To check if this is the case, you can `tail -f` the log, and see if the output you expected to see in your terminal goes there.

If that's the case, see if you can find a way to configure your webserver not to do that, or, if all else fails, try working with two terminals... (one for input, one for ouptut)

Comment: My webserver does not send its output to a log file.  It sends it to stdout. The other odd thing is when I kill the process - some, but not all, of the "stuck" output gets flushed to the log file at the end.  I'm starting to think that supervisor may be a little buggy ...

Comment: No ... my last comment is not really true ... it was not Supervisor's fault ... see my posted solution.